# Mathematica Link to NetLogo can't be aborted

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, netlogo

While using NetLogo 6.2.2 and Mathematica 13.1 in Mac OS 10.14.6 Mojave: When a NetLogo process is started by Mathematica, it's usually true that aborting the calculation (cmd-.) or quitting the Mma kernel stops that process (and quitting the kernel also shuts down the NetLog instance). What's new to me (since just a few months ago, I think) is the case of the Mma link being in an the infinite loop: I haven't found a way to recover from that. Neither of the two actions works, nor does quitting Mma. The only way I've found to stop the NetLogo instance that Mathematica created is to restart my machine. (I'm not sure which processes I'd have to ask the OS to kill, but the couple candidates that I tried didn't help.)

Here's how I got into the situation: Using the NLDoReportWhile[] command with a while condition that is always true. So, it's not actually the NetLogo code that is creating the infinite loop, it's the NLDoReportWhile[] command. This seems like a case where I wouldn't even have to quit the kernel; a simple abort of the Mma evaluation would work. Right? Again, I believe that I've used the Mathematica abort in the past to deal with this, but it's not working now. So it seems like a new miscommunication between Mathematica and NetLogo.